# Remove outliers for different groups

Tags: r, outliers

i am totally new here, so please be lenient with me :-)

I am looking for a solution to remove outliers which are different by a certain value in the same column:

`body_mass age
1   19  11
2   20  10
3   26  8
4   21  6
5   18  12
6   18  7
7   30  11
8   17  8
9   17  10
10  18  8`

[image: every age has different outliers - so what is a normal value (body_mass) for age 4, may be an outlier for age 0...]

```
boxplot(body_mass~age, data = df, subset=age %in% c(0:22))$out
outliers <- boxplot(body_mass~age, data = df, subset=age %in% c(0:22))$out

df[which(df$body_mass %in% outliers),]
df <- df[-which(df$body_mass %in% outliers),]
```

But trying this way, removes all values from all age, even they are just outliers for one age class

Comment: please excuse formatting...this is my thread

Comment: edit your question to add a tag for the language used (it looks like R to me, but I'm nor sure from your question, it could be another language that makes similar looking graphs) - this will help make sure people who could help see your question.

Comment: What do you define as an outlier? Statistically speaking. There are a few ways to define outliers depending on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on how you define "outlier". But if you are willing to accept that
an outlier is any value plus or minus 1.5 times the interquartile range, then you can use the following approach to remove outliers in body mass by age group.

Also, I assume you want to treat each age as a separate group because you didn't indicate otherwise.

Define a function that will replace outliers with `NA`.

```
#' Replace outliers
#'
#' Replace outliers with NA. Outliers are defined as values that fall outside plus or minus
#' 1.5 * IQR.
#'
#' @return Numeric vector of same length.
#' @param x Numeric vector to replace.
#' @param ... Other args passed to `quantile()`
#'
#' @export
replace_outliers <- function(x, ...) {
  qnt <- quantile(x, probs = c(.25, .75), ...)
  val <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y <- x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - val)] <- NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + val)] <- NA
  y
}
```

Apply `remove_outliers()` by age group and filter.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(age) %>% 
  mutate(body_mass = replace_outliers(body_mass)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(body_mass))
```

Comment: Thank you Giovanni. That was a solution i was looking for. I just have do thin about what you and als akash87 mentioned: Is this the right definition of outliers for my dataset..